# Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma With Infinite Orthonormal Base

Tags: linear-algebra

In an inner product space of infinite dimension, $V$, having an orthonormal base $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$,

There's the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma: $\forall u \in V$,  $\lim_{k\to\infty} \langle u, e_k\rangle = 0$.

Now looking at $\mathbb{R}^n$, with the series of $(1,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots)$,

How come the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma doesn't comply with it?

Thanks.

Comment: The norm of $(1,1,1,\dots)$ is too big.

Comment: Could you please try to clarify several things?  $\mathbb R^n$ is supposed to be infinite dimensional?  So $n$ is infinite?  And what do you mean by "series of $(1,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots)$"?  Is that supposed to correspond to $u$, or to the orthonormal basis?  Perhaps you mean $\ell^2$ in which case, as Henry W indicated, $(1,1,\ldots)$ is not in the space.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting close to the answer. Is Riemann-Lebesgue lemma defined only on spaces in which the norm has to be finite?

Comment: Taru: As you said, it is defined for an inner product space. An inner product space has to be a space that satisfies all of the properties in the definition of inner product space. You have not made clear even what space you are asking about.  But yes, a consequence of the definition is that each element has a norm that is a nonnegative real number.

Comment: @JonasMeyer : Riemann–Lebesgue applies only when the integral of the (first power of the) absolute value of the funciton is finite. It's not about inner product spaces.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks, my mistake was forgetting that context for that name; instead I took what Taru indicated they meant, which is about inner product spaces, a consequence of Bessel's inequality.

Comment: @JonasMeyer   what do you mean by saying "a consequence of Bessel's inequality"?

Comment: @weakmathematician: If $f$ is an element of an inner product space and $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal sequence, then $\sum_n|\langle f,e_n\rangle|^2\leq \|f\|^2$, which is Bessel's inequality.  A consequence of this is that if the sequence is infinite, then the series convergence implies the terms go to zero, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\langle f,e_n\rangle=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most frequently seen infinite-dimensional inner product space is isomorphic to the space of all sequences $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of scalars satisfying $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^2<\infty$. (If "scalars" means real numbers then one can write $a_n^2$ rather than $|a_n|^2$, but if it means complex numbers then one must write $|a_n|.)$ The sequence $(1,1,1,\ldots)$ is not a member of that space, since $1^2+1^2+1^2+\cdots\not<\infty.$

The Riemann–Lebesgue lemma applies to **integrable** functions, and "integrable" means the integral of the absolute value of the function is finite. Applied to functions on a bounded interval $[a,b]$, that means
$$
\int_a^b |f(x)|\,dx<\infty, \tag 1
$$
and on bounded intervals, that is a weaker statement than
$$
\int_a^b |f(x)|^2\,dx<\infty.
$$
Functions on a bounded interval that satisfy the condition $(1)$ stated above have Fourier series
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{2\pi in(x-a)/(b-a)}
$$
and the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma says $c_{\pm n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty.$ But the Riemann–Lebesgue lemma is not applicable when the condition $(1)$ given above does not hold.

BTW you'll notice I wrote Reimann–Lebesgue and not Riemann-Lebesgue. Some of the more fastidious publishers and Wikipedia insist on the former punctuation.